# Vulkan How to update data in push constants

Tags: vulkan

First i record a compute command buffer:

```
    void record_compute_command_buffer() {

        vk::CommandBufferBeginInfo begin_info{};
        begin_info.flags = vk::CommandBufferUsageFlagBits::eSimultaneousUse;

        GPU_.compute_command_buffer_.begin(begin_info);

        GPU_.compute_command_buffer_.bindPipeline(vk::PipelineBindPoint::eCompute, GPU_.compute_pipeline_);

        struct push_data {
            alignas(16) glm::mat4 view_matrix = camera_.get_view();
            alignas(16) glm::mat4 projection_matrix = glm::perspective(glm::radians(90.0f), GPU_.aspect_ratio(), 0.1f, 10.0f);
        } push;

        GPU_.compute_command_buffer_.pushConstants(GPU_.compute_pipeline_layout_, vk::ShaderStageFlagBits::eCompute, 0, sizeof(push), &push);

        GPU_.compute_command_buffer_.bindDescriptorSets(
            vk::PipelineBindPoint::eCompute, 
            GPU_.compute_pipeline_layout_, 
            0, 
            1, 
            &GPU_.compute_descriptor_sets_[0], 
            0, 
            nullptr
        );
        
        const int workgroup_size = 32;
        const int groupcount = ((models.size()) / workgroup_size) + 1;
        GPU_.compute_command_buffer_.dispatch(groupcount, 1, 1);

        GPU_.compute_command_buffer_.end();
    }
```

Then, in my `draw_frame` function i submit the buffer and start recording draw command buffers with synchronization:

```
    void draw_frame() {
        vk::SubmitInfo compute_submit_info{};
        compute_submit_info.commandBufferCount = 1;
        compute_submit_info.pCommandBuffers = &GPU_.compute_command_buffer_;

        GPU_.compute_queue_.submit(compute_submit_info);

        GPU_.logical_device_.waitForFences(GPU_.in_flight_fences[current_frame], true, UINT64_MAX);
        GPU_.logical_device_.resetFences(GPU_.in_flight_fences[current_frame]);

       // ... just a standard draw-frame code with semaphores and fences
    }
```

I know, each time I submit the compute command buffer, it is being executed the way it was recorded. This means the camera view matrix is always the same. But I need it for performing the compute shader culling! How can I update the compute command buffer? Should I `reset` and `record` it in `draw_frame`? I feel like it's wrong tho... Because I've already tried and faced synchronization issues. So is there any solution? Should I go with descriptor sets instead of push constants? I wouldn't like to since I have an integrated GPU so performance is crucial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using push constants for something that's likely to change every frame, or at least every few frames, is probably a bad idea.  You'd be better off using a persistently mapped uniform buffer that has memory that has `DEVICE_LOCAL_BIT | HOST_VISIBLE_BIT | HOST_COHERENT_BIT` bits.  Most modern GPUs have at least some of this memory.

Even if they don't you're probably still better off updating a uniform buffer via a staging buffer with a small transfer command buffer executed before the draw buffer, rather than re-recording your whole command buffer.

If you're using VMA for allocations, there's a bit that tries to optimize for this kind of memory:  `VMA_ALLOCATION_CREATE_HOST_ACCESS_ALLOW_TRANSFER_INSTEAD_BIT`.  See the advanced data uploading section on [this page](https://gpuopen-librariesandsdks.github.io/VulkanMemoryAllocator/html/usage_patterns.html).

Push constants are more useful when you want to do a number of draws that will be different in some respect that can be controlled through a push constant, but you don't want to change the pipeline or rebind anything.

For instance, say you have some small thing that you want to change between calls, but that doesn't change per-vertex OR per-instance.  Like say you have meshes for chess pieces, and you want to draw two sets of them, white and black, but you don't want to create separate mesh buffers with color in them and for some reason you don't want to have to put the color into instancing data. Push constants would be useful.

Sascha is correct that the only time you ever want to see `vk::Queue::waitIdle` or `vk::Device::waitIdle` is when you're starting up or shutting down the application.  You never want it in your render-loop.

I would go further than that and say that you should avoid resetting and re-recording any command buffer that's currently in use by either:

- Using a deletion queue / recycler mechanism
- Having more than one command buffer

### Deletion queue

In my code I have a deletion queue (I call it a recycler, but it doesn't really recycle anything) where I put any resources that I no longer need but which might be in use by the any previous frames' command buffers.

So for instance, when I need to record a new command buffer, I can push the current one into the deletion queue and just allocate a new one.  When I eventually submit my frame, I do so with a fence created for that frame, and I hand the fence to the deletion queue, which tells it "When this fence is signaled, anything pushed into the deletion queue prior to it is safe to delete".

### More than one command buffer

This one is easier to just explain with example code...

assume you have something like this

```cpp
struct Frame {
    vk::Fence submit_fence;
    vk::CommandBuffer command_buffer;

    void wait(const vk::Device& device) {
        // Wait for fence is decorated with [[nodiscard]]
        if (submit_fence) {
            device.waitForFences(submit_fence, true, UINT64_MAX);
            device.resetFences(submit_fence);
        } else {
            submit_fence = GPU_.logical_device_.createFence(vk::FenceCreateInfo{});
        }
    }
};
```

and then in your GPU class you had this...

```cpp
constexpr size_t MAX_FRAMES_IN_FLIGHT = 2;
struct GPU {
    ...
    std::array<Frame, MAX_FRAMES_IN_FLIGHT> compute_frames;
    size_t current_compute_frame = 0;
};
```

Then you could re-write your `draw_frame` function like this:

```cpp
void draw_frame() {
    auto &frame = GPU_.compute_frames[GPU_.current_compute_frame];
    frame.wait(GPU_.logical_device_);
    GPU_.compute_queue_.submit(vk::SubmitInfo{
        nullptr,  nullptr, // no wait semapores
        frame.command_buffer
    }, frame.submit_fence);
    GPU_.current_compute_frame = GPU_.current_compute_frame + 1 % MAX_FRAMES_IN_FLIGHT;
}
```

and change the beginning of `record_compute_command_buffer()` to look like this:

```cpp
void record_compute_command_buffer() {
    auto& frame = GPU_.compute_frames[GPU_.current_compute_frame];
    // No need for simultaneous flag
    frame.command_buffer.begin(vk::CommandBufferBeginInfo{});
    ...
```

You'd still need to be able to figure out which command buffers needed to be re-recorded, so you might want to put a `bool dirty` flag into the `Frame` type, so that when something changes that means all the command buffers are invalid, you can just set that on all of them, then clear it as you re-record each one (only ever recording one per frame).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! But as I mentioned earlier, I use all the possibilities the GPU can give. Mine is Intel Integrated UHD 620, if I use mapped buffers or descriptor sets e.g. for model-view-proj matrices (something that needs to be updated each frame), I face performance issues. 900 FPS with push constants and 400-500 FPS if using **anything** else. Thanks again tho!! I will remember that :)

Comment: Well, since I can't see your "everything else" you've tried I can't really speak to whether or not getting faster performance with a uniform buffer is impossible or not.  There are lots of reasons your push constant approach might be working faster than the uniform buffer approaches you may have tried that don't necessarily mean that the push constant approach will always be faster or even the fastest.  Iith the GPU you're using all memory is going to be device-local and host-visible / host coherent.  There are a few strategies you could use, esp if you're using more than one command buffer.

Comment: Yes you're right about the gpu memory properties, i'll try!

Answer (score 1):

Doing a wait idle (either device or queue) is bad practice and can have a severe performance impact. Esp. if you try to overlap compute and graphics, the device wait idle for each frame will completely kill any chance for overlapping work as it'll drain all (active) queues of the device.

A better option for your scenario (rebuilding command buffers for each frames) would be using fences to check for command buffer execution completion. You submit with such a fence, and before the next re-recording you check if that fence has been signaled before re-creating that command buffer.

Comment: I've seen that `queue.waitIdle` is equivalent to having submitted a valid fence. So what performance issues can it cause since the alternative is fence itself?

Answer (score 0):

Can't believe i forgot about `vk::Queue::waitIdle()` method:

```
    void draw_frame() {

        GPU_.compute_queue_.waitIdle();

        GPU_.compute_command_buffer_.reset();
        
        record_compute_command_buffer();

        vk::SubmitInfo compute_submit_info{};
        compute_submit_info.commandBufferCount = 1;
        compute_submit_info.pCommandBuffers = &GPU_.compute_command_buffer_;

        GPU_.compute_queue_.submit(compute_submit_info);    
        
        //...
```